# replace hypen with space (pointer error ) language c

Tags: c

i try to replace hypen with space but i have a warning: comparison between pointer and integer
for the line : if("%c" == '-')

I don't understand this message and why the program is not working

```
void lire_chaine(char ch[100]);

int main()
{
    
  char nom[100];

  printf("Entrez votre nom : ");
  lire_chaine(nom);
  printf("le nom est , %s\n",nom);

}

void lire_chaine(char ch[100])
{
    char car=' ' ;
    int i=0      ;

    while (car != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%c",&car);
        if("%c" == '-')
        ch[i] = ' ' ; 
        ch[i++]=car     ;
    }
    ch[i-1]='\0'; 


}
```

Comment: `if("%c" == '-')` -> `if(car == '-')`

Comment: What the program is expected to do? The effect of `ch[i] = ' ' ;` will be canceled by `ch[i++]=car     ;` anyway.

Comment: i want to replace '-' with ' '. 
thnks you Kaylum  it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this part

```
        if("%c" == '-')
        ch[i] = ' ' ;
```

Firstly, `"%c"` is a string literal. This is an array and it is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array here. On the other hand, `'-'` is a character constant, which is an integer. This is why you are "comparing between pointer and integer". Instead of this, you will want to compare the entered character `car` with the character constant `'-'`.

Secondly, even if you assign something to `ch[i]` here, it will be overwritten by the following `ch[i++]=car     ;`. It seems you should change `car` instead of that.

In conclusion, the part should be:

```
        if(car == '-')
            car = ' ' ;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and especially for the explanations!

I understand my mistakes.